# Ionic subheader bar overlapping content

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

In a view with header and subheader, subheader content overlaps the contents of the view.

- Header in slide menu

  ```
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
      <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left" ng-hide="$exposeAside.active"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  ```
- Subheader in a view

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar bar-subheader custom bar-energized" ng-if="datos.subTitulo">
      <div class="buttons">
         <a class="ion-chevron-left" href="#/app/ranking/ubicacion/{{datos.divAnt}}" ng-if="datos.divAnt"></a>
      </div>
      <h2 class="subtitle">{{datos.subTitulo}}</h2>
      <div class="buttons">
         <a class="ion-chevron-right" href="#/app/ranking/ubicacion/{{datos.divSig}}" ng-if="datos.divSig"></a>
      </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

`Div` buttons in `subheader` overlapping content, `h2` show 100%.
Something is missing in this code? Thanks

[image: image view]

[EDIT]
Rewrote the code to suit my needs: subheader smaller than the header with two links in the corners and a title.

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-subheader subheader_custom bar-energized">
    <div class="button button-clear"> 
        <a class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back blanco" href="#/app/ranking/ubicacion/{{datos.divAnt}}" ng-if="datos.divAnt"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="h2 title title_custom">{{datos.subTitulo}}</div>
    <div class="button button-clear"> 
        <a class="icon ion-ios-arrow-forward blanco" href="#/app/ranking/ubicacion/{{datos.divSig}}" ng-if="datos.divSig"></a>
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

Add this css:

```
.has-subheader {
    top: 70px;
}

.bar-subheader.subheader_custom {
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    top: 44px;
}
.title.title_custom {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    min-width: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Even buttons are not in line with the subheader title. Any ideas?

New status:
[image]

Answer (score 19):

Make sure that the content view knows it needs to leave space for the subheaders by adding the CSS class `has-subheader`:

```
<ion-content class="has-header has-subheader">
</ion-content>
```

See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#subheader

Comment: Yes,  ion content is:  <ion-content class="has-header has-subheader">. So the subheader overlapping de content, not de content overlapping the subheader

Comment: ah ok. what about the line `<h2 class="subtitle">{{datos.subTitulo}}</h2>`, is the class 'subtitle' defined? The regular ionic CSS shows only 'title' class also for subheader h2.

Comment: Edit answer to show css. Class subtitle now is title_custom. Thanks

Comment: now that you changed the height for the sub-bar and the height/line-height for the h2, you need to change the font-size and line-height/min-height for the buttons as well to fit into the smaller bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you face this issue in Android, then use the following

```css
.platform-android .bar-subheader  {
  top: 93px;
}
```

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/sub-header-not-showing-on-android-with-tabs/15341/18

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the height of the subheader, footer, and subfooter if you are using SASS with Ionic. If you want a 70px tall subheader simply add `$bar-subheader-height: 70px;` to your ionic.app.scss file. Your scss file should look something similar to:

```
// The path for our ionicons font files, relative to the built CSS in www/css
$ionicons-font-path: "../lib/ionic/fonts" !default;

$bar-subheader-height: 70px;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";
```

Check out the `www/lib/ionic/scss/_variables.scss` file for some of the other things you can change easily.

Here are [instructions for setting up sass with ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/sass.html) and here is a [quick tutorial](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/working-with-sass/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add `has-header` or `has-subheader` class to your main content in ion-content directive.

Here's my code:

```
<ion-view view-title="View Title">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="bar bar-header">
      <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="list has-header">
        <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
            Check mail
        </a>
        <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working"></i>
            Call Ma
            <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

`<div class="list has-header">` I add the `has-header` class to my list to avoid subheader overlapping